# PHP json_decode JSON string not decoding

Tags: php, json, decode

```
{ 
    "hintsacross": 
    [ { "number":"1" , "hinttext":"Hurt", "hintsquare":"A1" }, 
      { "number":"5" , "hinttext":"Make a selection", "hintsquare":"A6" }, 
      { "number":"8" , "hinttext":"Frank", "hintsquare":"A10" }
    ] ,
    "hintsdown": 
    [ { "number":"1" , "hinttext":"First Greek letter", "hintsquare":"A1" },
      { "number":"2" , "hinttext":"Used footnotes", "hintsquare":"A2" }, 
      { "number":"3" , "hinttext":"Listened to", "hintsquare":"A3" }
    ] 
 }
```

For some reason json_decode of PHP is not decoding this JSON.

Thanks in advance...

P.S. I am getting an error when this line 25 runs:

$temp = json_decode( $obj->hints,true );

**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected 'hintsacross' (T_STRING) in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\crosswords\query.blockouts.php** on line **25**

I validated my JSON through JSONlint and the parse error is coming out.

Comment: show us the code block you are using

Comment: invalid json.. comma(,) is missing newr by  ],
    "hintsdown": [

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is invalid JSON. Try adding a comma before "hintsdown" and retrying the json_decode.

```
{
    "hintsacross": [
        {
            "number": "1",
            "hinttext": "Hurt",
            "hintsquare": "A1"
        },
        {
            "number": "5",
            "hinttext": "Make a selection",
            "hintsquare": "A6"
        },
        {
            "number": "8",
            "hinttext": "Frank",
            "hintsquare": "A10"
        }
    ],
    "hintsdown": [
        {
            "number": "1",
            "hinttext": "First Greek letter",
            "hintsquare": "A1"
        },
        {
            "number": "2",
            "hinttext": "Used footnotes",
            "hintsquare": "A2"
        },
        {
            "number": "3",
            "hinttext": "Listened to",
            "hintsquare": "A3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: As an aside, it helps to validate your JSON using an online tool or other validator (I use JSONLint)

Answer (score 1):

```
   $ll="{ "hintsacross": [ { "number":"1" , "hinttext":"Hurt", "hintsquare":"A1" }, { "number":"5" , "hinttext":"Make a selection", "hintsquare":"A6" }, { "number":"8" , "hinttext":"Frank", "hintsquare":"A10" } ],
   "hintsdown": [ { "number":"1" , "hinttext":"First Greek letter", "hintsquare":"A1" }, { "number":"2" , "hinttext":"Used footnotes", "hintsquare":"A2" }, { "number":"3" , "hinttext":"Listened to", "hintsquare":"A3" } ] } "

    $ll = json_decode($ll);
    print_r($ll);
```

add (,) comma near

```
],
   "hintsdown"
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

The json is not in correct format. Use [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) to check this. You will get the error and if the json format is correct, you will get an okay message as well.

```
Parse error on line 18:
...A10"        }    ]"hintsdown": [     
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

Correct json :

```
{
    "hintsacross": [
        {
            "number": "1",
            "hinttext": "Hurt",
            "hintsquare": "A1"
        },
        {
            "number": "5",
            "hinttext": "Make a selection",
            "hintsquare": "A6"
        },
        {
            "number": "8",
            "hinttext": "Frank",
            "hintsquare": "A10"
        }
    ],
    "hintsdown": [
        {
            "number": "1",
            "hinttext": "First Greek letter",
            "hintsquare": "A1"
        },
        {
            "number": "2",
            "hinttext": "Used footnotes",
            "hintsquare": "A2"
        },
        {
            "number": "3",
            "hinttext": "Listened to",
            "hintsquare": "A3"
        }
    ]
}
```